# Python dataclasses_json: can I store many references to one object?

Tags: python, json, orm, python-dataclasses

I want to use `@dataclass_json` decorator to store my `@dataclass` instances.

And I want to have many reference to one object in the instances. And I want to have this reference structure saved (so that I could modify one settings object and the modifications would be applied to many objects that use the settings).

It can be easily done while the dataclass object lies in memory, but when I try to store it in JSON, it saves the copy of instance instead of a reference of it. Can I somehow deal with it?

P.S. Here's my code example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

from typing import List

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class RadarSettings:
    freq: float = 10e9
    prf: float = 1e-3


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Radar:
    name: str = ""
    preset_settings: RadarSettings = None  # Here should be references to some boilerplate preset settings for many radars
    custom_settings: RadarSettings = None  # And here should be the custom settings to this current radar


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class RadarScene:
    name: str = ""
    radars: List["Radar"] = None


preset = RadarSettings()

radar1 = Radar(name="mega search mode radar from hell", preset_settings=preset)

radar2 = Radar(name="satanic sensor array radar", preset_settings=preset)

# The preset_settings is one same object for both radars! If I modify it, the modifications will be applied to both radars
print(id(radar1.preset_settings), id(radar2.preset_settings))


scene_to_save = RadarScene(name="Infernal scene", radars=[radar1, radar2])

loaded_scene = RadarScene.from_json(scene_to_save.to_json())

print(id(loaded_scene.radars[0]), id(loaded_scene.radars[1])) 
# Alas! Here will be two instances of preset_settings saved. I need one =(
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have described is expected behavior. When you save your data to `json` format you get a string representation of the data that is plain text.

You may fix the issue with at least couple approaches.

Method 1.

Load `RadarScene` data, create `preset = RadarSettings()`, iterate over all `Radar`s in the `RadarScene` and update `preset_settings` attribute: `radar.preset_settings = preset`. This method can be incapsulated into `RadarScene` class so you can call it right after loading data.

Method 2.

Create new **singleton** class `RadarSettingsDefault` inherited from `RadarSettings` and modify `Radar` class: `preset_settings: RadarSettingsDefault = None`.

Comment: The problem is that I can have more than one preset. For example, I can have 5 radars. Two of them will have preset 1, three have preset 2...

Comment: @Felix Than method_1 still viable - iterate over `Radar`s inside `RadarScene` and create new `RadarSetting` object for every unique combination of `preset_settings` values.